# A question about suprema

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm always sort of uncomfortable with proofs involving suprema (I sort of skipped over whatever class in which I should have learned how it works).

I am trying to prove the following result about $L^p$ spaces for a class in measure theory:
$$ ||f||_p = \sup\bigg\{\int sf d\mu: s \text{ is a simple function, and } ||s||_q = 1\bigg\} := a(f)$$
where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Generally, when I want to show something is equal to the supremum of a set, I try to show a double inequality.  In this case, it's easy to show that $||f||_p \leq a(f)$ using Holder's inequality.  To show that $||f||_p \geq a(f)$, I have attempted the following simple proof:

By the definition of the supremum as the least upper bound, given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a simple function $s_\varepsilon$ such that $||s||_q = 1$ and:
\begin{align*}
a(f) - \varepsilon < \int s_\varepsilon f d\mu
\end{align*}
Using Holder's inequality:
\begin{align*}
\int s_\varepsilon f d\mu \leq \int |s_\varepsilon f|d\mu \leq ||s_\varepsilon||_q ||f||_p = ||f||_p
\end{align*}
That is, $a(f) - \varepsilon < ||f||_p$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.  Taking the limit of this inequality as $\varepsilon$ goes to zero, we conclude:
$$ a(f) \leq ||f||_p $$

Did I abuse some notion of supremum or of limits in doing this? I've tried to do a similar proof on another problem before, and was chastised for some sort of abuse, but I didn't really understand what I had done wrong, so now I'm suspicious!

Comment: I think your proof is right.

Comment: Holder's inequality gives $a(f) \leq ||f||_p$ as you have shown. It does not give the reverse inequality, so you still have to prove that $a(f) \geq ||f||_p$